# Android App Architecture to read and update databases

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, amazon-ec2

I'm writing an app with a local SQLite DB stored on the device and I wanted to periodically have the app Read and Update data to a database located on a web host or Amazon's EC2.

EC2 (e.g.) will store numbers from multiple users databases into one database, then crunch numbers from that database and store the statistics into a series of tables. My device will pull the data from these tables to display the statistics - most likely stored in another database located on the device.

**In short,
User updates the database on the tablet or phone ---> Tablet or phone sends data to EC2 (or other web host) ---> EC2 crunches numbers and sends calculated data (statistics) to tables ---> Tablet or phone pulls data from EC2 for display to user.**

Would I be looking at a content provider at EC2 (e.g.), or should I use a MySQL database on the EC2 end? What should my architecture be for this type of setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should watch the Google I/O talk on REST interfaces:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

Might point you in a better direction.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking at this now.

Answer (score 0):

**1-** Use SQlite on Device

**2-** Use a Database like SQL Server on your DB server.

**3-** Use a Web Service for exchanging data between the Device & DB server.

Comment: Thanks. 1 and 2 I understood but 3 is what really answered the q. REST looks to be what I am looking for.